# What does :attribute => parameter actually do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hard time understanding the form :attribute => parameter

Can anyone give me some explanations for it? Is :attribute a field (variable) belonging to the class or something else? Why we can pass this pair as one parameter to methods?

Comment: It's a ruby question, not a rails question. You should read about symbols in ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to something like this:

```
some_method(:foo => "bar", :baz => "abc")
```

then it's just shorthand which causes ruby to convert those things into a Hash. Please note that when using this form, that the hash must be the final argument to the method in order for this to work.

Based on the explanation above, this

```
some_method(:foo => "bar", :baz => "abc")
```

is ok, but this

```
some_method(:foo => "bar", :baz => "abc", moo)
```

is not.

Comment: When we use this form, what is actually passed? The value "bar" or the index :foo? Or the entire hash table?

Comment: @user1229490: The whole Hash, `f(:a => b)` is the same as `f({ :a => b })`.

Answer (score 0):

Though you will see this commonly in Rails, it is not a Rails specific question.  It is Ruby.

The answer to your question is that it is key/value pairs in a Hash, generally passed as an argument to a method.

You will see this as well when it is being assigned to a variable directly.  But let me show you a sample method, and a sample usage, so that you can put them together:

```
def some_method(*args, name: 'Joe', amount: 42, **other_params )
  puts "#{name}, #{amount}, glob of arguments = #{args.inspect}",
       "other params #{other_params}"
end

some_method(:occupation => 'programmer', :phone => '123-456-7890', name: 'Jane')
```

This is Ruby 2.0.0 specific in the fact that you can provide for that last argument, which provides for unnamed parameters, in practice.  Using the 1.9+ syntax for a Hash in the argument list, you are allowed to provide for other unnamed "parameters" which can appear after the hash argument.

Notice that if I had used the older syntax for Hash, namely the :key => 'value' syntax, I would not be allowed (at least as of this writing) to have the **other_params argument at the end of the argument list.

You could also provide the hash using the newer syntax in the calling code, though I left it as the Hash syntax when calling some_method.

The Hash still needs to be the last provided in the calling argument list, the same as indicated in the argument list for the method definition.